# Pine Script - Numbering Buy and Sell signals

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I am trying to make this script to show long1 & long2 and short1 & short2

Please check images below.

[Original Chart Signal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhRFh.png)

Original) long -> short -> long -> short -> long -> short

[Modified Chart Signal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQcJG.png)

Modified) long1 -> short1 -> long2 -> short2 -> long1 -> short1

Is it possible to make this modification using pine script?

I cannot find regarding this numbering signals.

```
// Smooth Average Range

per1 = input(defval=27, minval=1, title="Fast period")
mult1 = input(defval=1.6, minval=0.1, title="Fast range")

per2 = input(defval=55, minval=1, title="Slow period")
mult2 = input(defval=2, minval=0.1, title="Slow range")

smoothrng(x, t, m) =>
    wper = t * 2 - 1
    avrng = ema(abs(x - x[1]), t)
    smoothrng = ema(avrng, wper) * m
    smoothrng
smrng1 = smoothrng(source, per1, mult1)
smrng2 = smoothrng(source, per2, mult2)
smrng = (smrng1 + smrng2) / 2

// Range Filter

rngfilt(x, r) =>
    rngfilt = x
    rngfilt := x > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? x - r < nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : x - r : 
       x + r > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : x + r
    rngfilt
filt = rngfilt(source, smrng)

upward = 0.0
upward := filt > filt[1] ? nz(upward[1]) + 1 : filt < filt[1] ? 0 : nz(upward[1])
downward = 0.0
downward := filt < filt[1] ? nz(downward[1]) + 1 : filt > filt[1] ? 0 : nz(downward[1])

hband = filt + smrng
lband = filt - smrng

longCond = bool(na)
shortCond = bool(na)
longCond := source > filt and source > source[1] and upward > 0 or source > filt and source < source[1] and upward > 0
shortCond := source < filt and source < source[1] and downward > 0 or source < filt and source > source[1] and downward > 0

CondIni = 0
CondIni := longCond ? 1 : shortCond ? -1 : CondIni[1]

long = longCond and CondIni[1] == -1
short = shortCond and CondIni[1] == 1

// Plotting

plotshape(long, title="Long", text="Long", style=shape.labelup, textcolor=color.black, size=size.tiny, location=location.belowbar, color=color.lime, transp=0)
plotshape(short, title="Short", text="Short", style=shape.labeldown, textcolor=color.white, size=size.tiny, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0)

// Alerts

alertcondition(long, title="Long", message="Long")
alertcondition(short, title="Short", message="Short")
```

This is the orignal signal script.

It would be great if anyone can help me to modifiy signals.

Thank you.

Tried modify script, but there is no information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `var` counter and increase it every time your condition is `true`. Then check whether if it is a odd number or not.

```
// Plotting
var long_cnt = 0
var short_cnt = 0

long_cnt := long ? long_cnt + 1 :  long_cnt
short_cnt := short ? short_cnt + 1 :  short_cnt

is_long_1 = (long_cnt % 2) == 0
is_short_1 = (short_cnt % 2) == 0

plotshape(long and is_long_1, title="Long 1", text="Long 1", style=shape.labelup, textcolor=color.black, size=size.tiny, location=location.belowbar, color=color.lime, transp=0)
plotshape(short and is_short_1, title="Short 1", text="Short 1", style=shape.labeldown, textcolor=color.white, size=size.tiny, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0)
plotshape(long and not is_long_1, title="Long 2", text="Long 2", style=shape.labelup, textcolor=color.black, size=size.tiny, location=location.belowbar, color=color.lime, transp=0)
plotshape(short and not is_short_1, title="Short 2", text="Short 2", style=shape.labeldown, textcolor=color.white, size=size.tiny, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0)
```

[image]